# HTML Meta Tags and HTTPS

Tags: html, meta

Currently all my pages are served via HTTP, but I'm looking to update the server to use HTTPS only.

(Possibly detect if the user is connecting via HTTP or HTTPS)

Most pages have META Tags as follows:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Will these still be valid or will they need changing for HTTPS ?
Is there anyway to allow HTTP & HTTPS TAGS within the same page without upsetting either ?

Thanks

Comment: HTTP-EQUIV is not affected by HTTPS - they are not related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will still be valid, since the [meta attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) remains the same over HTTP and HTTPS.